# ObjectDataSource and select method in same class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to have an objectdatasource and its select method in the same class?

```
public class Class1(): System.Web.UI.Page
{

   protected void Page_load(object sender,EventArgs e)
   {
     this.ObjectDataSource1.TypeName="Class1";
     this.ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod="GetData";
     this.ObjectDataSource1.DataBind();
   }

   public Ilist<object> GetData()
   {
   //return list here
   }
}
```

> I am getting error "the type specified in the TypeName property could not be found"

Comment: Try using the full qualified name, including the namespace as the `TypeName`.

Comment: i tried it.didnt work.

Comment: What is your namespace, what did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: namespace is myapp1.i tried TypeName="myapp1.Class1".I got the error "the type specified in the TypeName property could not be found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of typing it by hand use [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method:

```
this.ObjectDataSource1.TypeName = this.GetType().FullName;
```

This should be enough. If not, you can try `AssemblyQualifiedName` instead of `FullName`.